# How to print an HTML Table multiple times inside a custom email template in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.3, email-templates, html

In custom email template placed at:
**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/email/custom_email_template.html**

I have a table which prints structure of a giftcard in email, For Example like this:
[image]
and table printing it is(suppose):

```
                    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;border-spacing:0px;"> 
                          <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;"> 
                            <td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-bottom:10px;">
                              <div style="background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center;height: 220px;width: 360px;">
                                <span style="font-size: 50px;font-weight: bold;color: #36bde5;display: inline-block;margin-top: 20px;margin-left: 70px;">660</span>
                                <div style="background-color: #fff;width: 300px;height: 105px;border-radius: 25px;margin-top: 17px;margin-left: 5px;">
                                  <span style="display: inline-block;margin-top: 30px;margin-bottom: 10px;font-size: 24px;">56876478</span>
                                  <span style="display: block;font-size: 12px;color: #707070;">valable jusqu’au : 15 / 08 / 2020</span>
                                </div>
                              </div >
                            </td> 
                          </tr>
                        </table>
```

If I have more then one gift cards to send in one email, how can I print the HTML content multiple times ? I can get amount value multiple times as:

```
<strong>{{var templateVars.amount|raw}}</strong>
```